# Is it possible to have 2 'then' in an if statement

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual studio 2017, and I am trying to know which image a picture box has, the reason I do not know is because it is being loaded from a image list with 6 pictures, I looked and tried many ways but cannot figure out the index of the image from the image list, so I decided to set the tag of the picture box to have the image index at the time it is loaded,

```
If rNum = 1 Then d1.Image = imgDice.Images(0) Then (d1.Tag = 0)
```

This does not work, but does it make sense? Is it possible to have two then statements on one line therefore saving me an end if?
If this where just one if statement like the one above I don't mind doing end if, but since I have about 6 of them it would be much easier like this way. Perhaps it is something like

```
And Then
```

Comment: I think the second `Then` should be `Else` ?  You should keep a collection somewhere tracking which image is showing rather than evaluating a bitmap object.  That probably wont work like you think it does

Comment: @Plutonix No, he's trying to shoehorn two statements into one line.

Comment: Else would make it that if rNum is not 1 Then (d1.Tag = 0) I want it if it is 1 then Then d1.Image = imgDice.Images(0) and (d1.Tag = 0)

Comment: Ok, then dont use a single line `IF`.  I confess I couldnt tell what was being attempted

Comment: @plutonix if it was just one statement then i would but I have about 6 such statements and would take lots more room.

Comment: Use a block if statement to include multiple things for each copndition [`IF...Then...Else` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this ALL the time.  You can use a colon as so:

```
If rNum = 1 Then d1.Image = imgDice.Images(0): (d1.Tag = 0)
```

Comment: that is to have something on the same line, not a second then to the if statement, that would do it even if rNum is not 1

Comment: @vbdevelp It will only execute the two statements if the If fires.  Try it.